# Update a variable in SSIS Custom component not persistent as the process terminates

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, custom-component

i am currently developing a ssis custom component , in the design time i create a user variable and update it any time i want perfectly.

Now, when i execute the package, and in the `PrimeOutput` method i update the variable  successfully, but when the process terminates the variable is not persistent and the only value i get is the old value.
here is how i update the variable :

```
IDTSVariables100 variables = null;
VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite(name, ref variables);
variables[name].Value = newValue;
variables.Unlock();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your variable name is `MyVar`

```
 VariableDispenser variableDispenser = (VariableDispenser)this.VariableDispenser;
 variableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::myVar");

 IDTSVariables100 vars;
 variableDispenser.GetVariables(out vars);

 // Set the variable
 vars["User::myVar"].Value = newValue;

 // Unlock the variable
 vars.Unlock();
```

For more info you can refer to this useful links:

- http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-use-variables-in-script.html
- https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/read-and-write-variables-in-a-script-component-in-ssis-sql-server-integration-services-using-c/

**Update 1**

*After reading your comment `"but after the package finish executing, the variable reset to the old value"`*

The variable value stored in the package file by default is the one you specified when designing the package *(programmatically or using visual studio)*

Also if changing the variable value inside a script it will change the value only when executing, and the new value cannot be readed from another component inside the same `DataFlow Task` the value will be committed when the Current `DataFlow Task` finished executing

**Useful Links**

*If you are interested to edit packages programmatically you can refer to the following links*

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/creating-a-package-programmatically
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/building-packages-programmatically/working-with-variables-programmatically
- [How to edit SSIS packages programatically in VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218229/how-to-edit-ssis-packages-programatically-in-vb)

Comment: i have tried this before, it's the same logic as my code does , as i mentioned before that the variable value has changed actually, but after the package finish executing, the variable reset to the old value .

Comment: @MohamedMekdad what you mean by *"after the package finish executing"*? did you mean the dataflow task or the whole package?

Comment: i am developing a Custom Data Flow Component (a CRM source Component ) , and yes after the dataflow Component  finish executing.

Comment: @MohamedMekdad where you are trying to read the variable?  Another dataflow task? Or when reexecute the package?

Comment: I did read the variable , and i did update it inside the `PrimeOutput ` of the Component  , but the changes are applied only while the Component is executing , once it finished , all the changes made on the variable does not committed.